# How do I display PHP code instead of displaying output?

Tags: php

I have a string variable which also has some PHP code in it. The code in the string var is getting run whenever I am displaying the string with echo. Is there anything (function) which can escape the meaning of PHP code while I use it with string?

Please help?

Comment: Could you post your code? Echoing the php code should not execute it.

Comment: I got confuse actually, that code had a meta tag refresh, which was executing and page was getting loaded whenever I try to load that page. It's fixed, what a silly mistake. Yes you guys are right, we can't execute php code in echo. Anyways, thank you all guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using single quotes

```
echo 'foo is $foo';
```

will return foo is $foo

For more references: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are already outputting the string, you might want to substitute `echo` for:

- [`highlight_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) — Syntax highlighting of a string

Comment: very interesting, cookie for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute PHP code by echo it to web browser by HTTP.

I mean you think about HTML, you can use `htmlspecialchars` to escape html code and print it without parse by browser like a HTML code.